# Output file with one byte per line in hex format (under linux bash)

Tags: bash, output, hexdump

As the title says, here is an example:

```
$ cat test.txt 
ABCD
$ hd test.txt 
00000000  41 42 43 44 0a                                    |ABCD.|
00000005
```

my desired output would be:

```
41
42
43
44
```

I know that this is possible with sed, awk and stuff, but this might be very slow for large files. I thought of an format string for "hexdump" or a parameter combination for "od". Could you please help me out?

Comment: what do you want to do with newlines?

Comment: Oh, the newline just appeared in this example, the real file I want work with does not have newlines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
od -An -vtx1 -w1 test.txt | cut -c2-
```

If you don't want newlines:

```
od -An -vtx1 -w1 test.txt | cut -c2- | fgrep -v 0a
```

Meaning of `od` options:

- `-An` : addresses: no
- `-v` : verbose, i.e., don't write a `*` instead of repeating lines
- `-tx1` : output type: hex, 1 byte (use `-tx1z` for an `hd`-like output)
- `-w1` : max width: 1

One nice thing about [`od`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_%28Unix%29) is that it's available on any `*x` system.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what i needed. Now that I have your examples I understand the manpage of od. Great job!

Comment: Unfortunately, no `od -w` on macOS

Comment: on macOS there is a `gsed` (`brew install gnu-sed`), and a few more, but unfortunately no `god` ;-)

Answer (score 14):

```
$ echo -n 'ABCD' | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x\n"'
41
42
43
44
0a
```

If you don't want it to print `0a` at the end for the newline then I'd recommend getting rid of the newline from the file first.

Comment: I prefer this one because I can add '0x' as a prefix or 'h' as a postfix.

Comment: Works perfect even with `0d`and `0a`.